# check with Webdriver if browser is still open

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver

I'm using nodejs and webdriver. Its running an infinite loop until I close the browser (thats the idea). Now the question is how I can detect if I close the browser. This is how I've initialized webdriver:

```
import webdriver from 'selenium-webdriver';
let browser = new webdriver.Builder().usingServer().withCapabilities({
            'browserName': 'chrome',
            'reuse_browser': false
        }).build();
```

Any guidance on this subject would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `try/catch` method doesn't work because the webdriver functions run asynchronously. Instead use `.then()/.catch()`.

```
driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(link){
    //Browser is open
    resolve(true);
  }).catch(function(){
    //Browser was closed
    resolve(false)
  });
```

You only need to `resolve` if you embed this code in a promise, say, to have an easy-to-call `browserExists` function.

Answer (score 4):

You can catch the error that will get thrown by the Selenium JavaScript bindings if the browser has been closed:

```
Error: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used.
```

see [selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js) around line 402:

```
function checkHasNotQuit() {
if (!self.session_) {
  throw new error.NoSuchSessionError(
    'This driver instance does not have a valid session ID ' +
    '(did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be ' +
    'used.');
 }
```

The "session_" variable on the browser object will be available simply as browser.session_ -- however, due to asynchronicity, it may not accurately show if the browser has closed.

Instead, you can send a dummy interaction with the browser, like driver.getTitle(), then catch the error to check if the browser has closed:

```
try{
  driver.getTitle();
  // browser is open
} catch(NoSuchSessionError) {
  // browser is closed
}
```

Comment: The latest approach with the try/catch worked for me.