# How To Allow Only One ChromeDriver At A Time Using Selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

I currently have a simple method which initiate a `ChromeDriver` using the following method:

```
public void ChromeDriver()
{
    ChromeDriverStart();
}
```

`ChromeDriverStart()` refers to a public method in which I set the options for the driver which I have set using `IWebDriver`. Now let's say I will initiate a driver named `driverx`, I only want it to be initiated if there is not already an instance of `driverx`  active. So far I tried the following if-statement inside the method: `if (driverx = null)`

My goal is to not start another instance of driverx when calling the method ChromeDriver().

Whole Code:

```
public IWebDriver 1driver;
public IWebDriver 2driver;
public IWebDriver 3driver;
public IWebDriver 4driver;

public void DriverStart() 
{
    1driver = new ChromeDriver();
}

public void Driver()
{
    if (driver1 = null)
    {
        DriverStart();
    }
}
```

Comment: check this already answered post [execute selenium in already opened Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69188369/webdriverio-how-to-execute-selenium-script-in-already-opened-browser)

Comment: this is another answer to check if the driver is started, but with the `then()/catch/` method, i do not code in `C#`, so adapt it to your need [is browser still open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36828639/check-with-webdriver-if-browser-is-still-open)

Comment: Not was I am asking for. I want to avoid starting the same driver multiple times without using the a debugging address.

Comment: okay post the whole code of  the the `function` and options you used , others can help you more if you mentioned what you have tried clearly!!

Comment: The second link looks more promising, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Archiee I just did.

Comment: how about this answer[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27616470/webdriver-how-to-check-if-browser-still-exists-or-still-open](is browser exit or open) , there also an explanation between`close()` and `quite()`

Answer (score 0):

A different approach than other answers mentioned in the comments would be to use DI.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Support" Version="4.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="4.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="107.0.5304.6200" />
</ItemGroup>
```

```
// .NET 6 Console app

using IHost host = Create(args).Build();
using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
var provider = scope.ServiceProvider;

var driver1 = provider.GetRequiredService<IWebDriver>();
var driver2 = provider.GetRequiredService<IWebDriver>();

// If we use the scoped service only the one driver will be initiated.
// If we select to configure our service as transient then 
// both instances will be initiated

driver1.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://stackoverflow.com/");
driver2.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://stackoverflow.com/");

static IHostBuilder Create(string[] args) =>
         Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
        {
            // Uncomment one of them
            // services.AddScoped<IWebDriver, ChromeDriver>();
            // services.AddTransient<IWebDriver, ChromeDriver>();
        });
```

Of course this is a simple implementation of DI just for this demo. You will probably need to configure the drivers in different manner than your initial implementation. Maybe you could create a concrete class that injects `IWebDriver` and configure it according to your needs and then add it to DI as well.

Finally let me cut a long story short, using dependency injection you will have all your services into one location and also you can handle their lifecycles.

Answer (score 0):

Use the comparison operator to test for null:

```
if (driver1 == null)
{ //        ^^
    driver1 = new ChromeDriver();
```

The `=` operator is the assignment operator. The comparison operator uses two equals signs side-by-side: `==`.